# Is it possible to center an image on both axis inside a div?

Tags: jquery, css, html, centering

I have a script that loads in a div with images running jQuery Cycle Lite Plugin.

I got the tip that I could us the "after" function in that plugin to make changes to the picture each time the image is refreshed. So I wrote this:

```
$("#display div").css({  
  margin: "0 auto",  
  "text-align": "center",  
});
```

The html built like this:

```
<div id="display">
  <div id="slideshow1">
     <img ... />  
  </div> 
</div>
```

This isn't working, whats wrong?
( this is supposed to center it horizontally, i need to center it vertically to )..

**edit:**
I kind of got it working but it still needs help, anyone that knows why its acting weird?
http://hem.bredband.net/noor/bildspelet.html

thanks @pekka for the link

Comment: dupli- tripli- quadruplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=center+image+vertically but I'm pretty sure there's a jquery plugin as well that makes it easier.

Comment: Found one: http://www.seodenver.com/simple-vertical-align-plugin-for-jquery/

Comment: I know this is a common problem, but somehow it isn't working, i thought it had something to do with the jQuery Cycle plugin.. and tables is not an option since i need it to be fullscreen. sorry though for creating another thread about this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, trailing commas in JavaScript objects is bad stuff, remove the last comma.

Second of all you could probably calculate it like so:

```
var $div = $('#display');
$div.css('position', 'relative');

var $kids = $div.children(); 
// I'm assuming you want to center all the slideshows?
$kids.each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.css({
    left: ($div.innerWidth(true) - $this.width()) / 2,
    top: ($div.innerHeight(true) - $this.height()) / 2,
    position: 'absolute'
  });
});
```

From looking at your sample: your `<div id="display">` needs to have a height set (even 100%) in the css, or it will always shrink to contain (which when all children are made absolute positioning, the height will fold to zero).  Please take a look at the [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/asesa)

Comment: I did this now, but it's not working.. you're right about me wanting to center all the images. here's a link to what i've got right now: http://hem.bredband.net/noor/bildspelet.html It's acting weird..

Answer (score 0):

For stuff like this, the CSS solution is always preferable to the JS one, because a) it works with JavaScript turned off and b) it works immediately with no delay and with no timing issues related to making sure the layout has flowed into its final resting place. But is there a CSS solution in this case?

**CSS**

There is no way, with the markup you've given, to center an image vertically in a cross-browser way (included IEs 6-8) with just CSS. However, a small change to your markup to include a wrapping single-celled table, and then you can center vertically with `vertical-align:middle`. Your markup would look like this:

```
<div id="display">
  <div id="slideshow1">
     <table cellspacing=0><tr><td style="height:200px;padding:0;vertical-align:middle">
       <img ... />
     </td></tr></table>  
  </div> 
</div>
```

Extra HTML cruft but it keeps it centered with no script running even as the image dimensions change.

**JS**

If you want to use JavaScript instead it looks like gnarf has the right idea (except why did he name all his variables starting with the dollar sign?) I'd take that and move the body into a named function so you can call it whenever you want (say `recenter`). For the initial render you want it to happen as soon as possible, so I'd inline the call to `recenter()` immediately after your slideshow DIVs in the markup.

Comment: Just like you're saying, I'd prefer to use as little JavaScript as possible, I'll try to do what you've suggested right away! (I'll keep that in min next time i'll do my own javascript -no $ signs that is)

Comment: I've almost got it,

var thelistt = localStorage.getItem('thelist')
var trt = document.createElement("div");
 trt.setAttribute("Id","slideshow1");
 trt.className="pics";

 $('#display').append(trt);

var tble = document.createElement("table");
 tble.setAttribute("cellspacing","0");
 tble.innerHTML = "<tr><td style='height:200px;padding:0;vertical-align:middle'>";
 $('#slideshow1').append(tble);
 trt.innerHTML += thelistt;
 trt.innerHTML += "</td></tr>";


$('#slideshow1').cycle();
});

can you spot any errors?

Comment: It's hard to say reading it on one line like that. Isn't localStorage not cross browser? I'm sure IE6 doesn't support it at least.

Comment: The dollar sign is a convention for indicating that the variable refers to a jQuery object (ie, the result of a query: `$divs = $('div');`) as opposed to a non-jQuery object: `divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');`

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't aware of that convention, I always thought the dollar sign was used for "special" variables, like double underscore in python. I guess you learn something every day.