# What's the proper workaround for creating a div with a table in it with images in the table?

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamic

I want this:

```
<div id="display">
  <div id="slideshow1">
     <table cellspacing=0><tr><td style="height:200px;padding:0;vertical-align:middle">
       <img ... />
     </td></tr></table>  
  </div> 
</div>
```

And I'm using this:

```
var thelistt = localStorage.getItem('thelist')
   var trt = document.createElement("div");
    trt.setAttribute("Id","slideshow1");
    trt.className="pics";  

    $('#display').append(trt);  

var tble = document.createElement("table");
    tble.setAttribute("cellspacing","0");
    tble.innerHTML = "<tr><td style='height:200px;padding:0;vertical-align:middle'>";
    $('#slideshow1').append(tble);
    trt.innerHTML += thelistt;
```

This creates a div, then a table, closes the table, then images, then closes div..

Isn't there a smoother way to not do all this, if someone'd take a look at my current code i''m sure you'd get a good laugh :

http://hem.bredband.net/noor/bildspelet3.html

(you need to click on edit and put in two or more urls directly to images)

Comment: Sure, output the HTML with the page and then use jQuery to just play with the images.

Comment: What animuson said. You can set #display to display:none in the CSS to begin with, and show it once an image is injected via jQ. On another note, is there any reason you are using tables for this?

Comment: I've done this now, everything is fine, all i need now is to center the images since they show up but not centered..

the reason for the tables is here : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692560/is-it-possible-to-center-an-image-on-both-axis-inside-a-div/2692724#2692724

If you have any other solution i'd really like to hear it! thanks!

Comment: Something is still off, @animuson @bobsoap, anyone of you know what the problem could be? ->

http://hem.bredband.net/noor/bildspelet2.html

Strange..

Comment: It frightens me that people are starting to use Javascript as a crutch to do what server-side processes should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
var $display = jQuery('<div>').attr('id', 'display');
var $slideshow1 = jQuery('<div>').attr('id','slideshow1');
var $td = jQuery('<td>').attr('style','height:200px;padding:0;vertical-align:middle');

var $tr = jQuery('<tr>');
var $table = jQuery('<table>').attr('cellspacing', '0').append($tr.append($td));

jQuery('body').append($display.append($slideshow1.append($table)));
```

Will create this html:

```
<div id="display">
  <div id="slideshow1">
    <table cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="height: 200px; padding: 0pt; vertical-align: middle;">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

To add an image you can use a similar pattern.

There are more efficent ways this could be structured, probably into one statement, but i was going for clarity :)

HTH